# Can I open Notepad.exe from C# with "Find" option opened?

Tags: notepad, process.start

I created a Window form C# application which opens a Notepad.exe using command:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", w_file);
```

But I want to open the Notepad with option "Edit-Find" and put some value into the "Find" field.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to automate something...

Here is a sample from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C) which will help you to do what you are looking for in C#